# Find all functions holomorphic in a punctured unit disk such that $zf' + 2f = 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I think all such functions are of the form $c/z^2$ where $c$ is a constant. I'd like to expand it as a taylor series about $0$ and then compare coefficients of $f$ and $f'$ but I don't know whether it is holomorphic at $0$.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{f’}{f}=\frac{-2}z$$

Comment: I thought about the argument principle and of integrating it, but the first doesn't do anything since I don't see why zeros are relevant and the second has the problem of a branch cut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note first that $f(z) \ne 0$, if $z \ne 0$ since otherwise if $m \ge 1$ is the order of $f$ at such a $z_o$, $f'$ has order $m-1$ and we get a contradiction after simplifying $(z-z_0)^{m-1}$.

Hence we get $\frac{f'}{f}=-\frac{2}{z}$ on $D^{*}$, so on any domain that consists of $D^{*}$ from which we cut a segment going from the origin to the boundary (which makes it simply connected), $f(z)=\frac{c}{z^2}$ with $c$ apriori depending on the segment removed; however since any two such domains have non-empty open intersection, the constant must be the same by the identity principle, so we are done and indeed $f(z)= \frac{c}{z^2}$ on the whole $D^{*}$

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by simplifying? Also what is $D*$? And how do we get $f$ is of the described form? Do we integrate the derivative of the natural log of $f$?

Comment: $f$ has order $m \ge 1$ at $z_0$, means $f(z)=(z-z_0)^mg(z), g(z_0) \ne 0, f'(z)=(z-z_0)^{m-1}h(z), h(z_0) \ne 0$; substitut,simplify and let $z=z_0$ you get $z_0h(z_0)=0$, contradiction

Comment: Thanks. $D*$ is just the domain in the question? And could you explain how we get $f$?

Comment: $D^{*}$ is the punctured disc sure; then if you have a simply connected domain U included in $D^{*}$ ( for example cutting out a segment as noted), you can fix a base point in U and integrate the equation $\frac{f'}{f}+\frac{2}{z}=0$ on any path connecting the base point to any other point in U as the integral is path independent by simple connectedness; this leads to $\log f +\log z^2 =c_U$, hence $f(z)=\frac{c_U}{z^2}$ on U; then use two such to cover the full $D^{*}$ etc

Comment: Thanks! Lastly, why is the integral of $f'/f$ = $log f(b) - log f(a)$ on any path from $a$ to $b$ in a simply connected domain?

Comment: Technically on any such U simply connected, $f(z) \ne 0$ means there is a (and hence many, with all differing by $2k\pi i$) function $h$ that is "$\log f$" is the sense that $e^h=f, h'=\frac{f'}{f}$. Fixing the base point $z_0$ in U and a value of $\log {f(z_0)}, \log {z_0^2}$ gives both a fixed such logarithm and the constant $c_U=\log {f(z_0)}+\log {z_0^2}$ by path integration as noted above; exponentiating we get $f(z)=\frac{c_U}{z^2}$

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of calculus $\int_{\gamma}g'(z)dz=g(\gamma(1))-g(\gamma(0))$ for any parametrization $z=\gamma(t), 0 \le t \le 1$ since obviously $g'(z)dz=g'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt=(g(\gamma(t)))'dt$ and clearly $(\log f)'=\frac{f'}{f}$ by the usual properties of the logarithm, while $\gamma(1)=b, \gamma(0)=a$ by our choice to connect the two points

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $g(z) = z^2 f(z)$. $g$ is holomorphic in the punctured disk, with
$$
 \color{red}{g'(z)} = 2zf(z) + z^2f'(z) = z(2f(z) + zf'(z)) \color{red}{= 0 \, .}
$$
It follows that $g$ is *constant:*
$$
 g(z) = c \implies f(z) = \frac{c}{z^2} \, .
$$

Comment: Slick.. does a similar method work if it were $3f(z)$ instead of $2f(z)$?

Comment: @Saad: Sure. If $zf' + nf = 0$ with an integer $n$ then $g(z) = z^n f(z)$ has a zero derivative.

Comment: Nice! What if it were $z^2f'$ instead (though that surely changes the family of solutions)

Comment: @Saad: The same idea works. First integrate the differential equation $z^2f' + 2f = 0$ so see that solutions are of the form $f(z) = c\exp(2/z)$. Then, for a formal proof, consider $g(z) = \exp(-2/z)f(z)$ and show that the derivative is zero. The nice thing about this approach is that you don't have to argue about local vs. global solutions, or the choice of integration paths.